# Is there any solution that enable LAZY FETCH when implementing Serializable

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, serializable

I have 3 Entities Name A ,B and BAudits (here is the code snippet):

```
@Entity
...
@BatchSize(size = 1000)
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A implements Serializable
{
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_CODE", referencedColumnName = "B_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private B b;
    ...
}

@Entity
...
@BatchSize(size = 1000)
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B implements Serializable
{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JsonManagedReference
    @NotAudited
    private Set<BAudits> bAudits;
    ...
}

BAudits is just a normal entity
```

Where B_CODE(String) is the fk for A and B .When I try to run the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM A a where a.id IN (**);
[ ** is just a list of id]
```

I found that the lazy fetch will not work and tons of B will be fetched(and that is why I set the fetchtype as lazy)

**I knew that the problems should be Serializable** and I tried different ways to let it works (and it fails) but I the have no idea if there are any ways that can let the lazy fetch work.

- for the dao. It extended JpaRepository<A, Long>

Comment: Hello! How do you know that `implements Serializable` is the cause of your trouble? It looks strange to me. When your remove the `implements Serializable`, the SQL statement works then as expected?

Comment: for sure I know Serializable is the reason(as I mentioned. **Also B_CODE is not an "id" and I do need to use Serializable to let A and  B can join together**). And that is why I want to find if there are any solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Then it means that some part of your application asks for a serialization somewhere (=> `B b` is queried and lazy "lost" by the loading it causes). I don't know if a serialization uses a getter or only the member variable to be performed. If it's when the serializer examines the member variable that the loading is caused, then maybe putting annotation on getters instead of members variables could allow serialization to be done without triggering the load that ends the lazy. But this will make you move all your annotations from members variables to methods, to check, which is boring to do.

Comment: sorry I am not really understand what does it means. Would you mind provide some example for my understanding?

Comment: If lazy doesn't work (it returns plenty of `B` items) it means that someone used the `b` variable in your code to start the loading of its content. It can only be a seralization process, as you implemeted `Serialize` and said that it's the cause of your trouble.

Comment: I am not sure if I get it right or not. What you mean is that in Serialize. Some process will be invoked to trigger the B? as in my Serialize. It is just an empty class and has nothing